# Query Custom Meta Value with Increment

Tags: wp-query, loop, query, query-posts, post-meta

I have a Query searching for a meta value I have added to my posts (meta-select). I have it feeding out in a loop with 4 results. Let's say I want this loop to start with the meta value "2" and work its way up "3","4","5" each time adding 1 to the value in the loop. Here is my current code which obviously just queries for the value "2" where do I add an increment in this function?

```
<?php 

// args
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 4,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key' => 'meta-select',
    'meta_value' => '2'
);

// get results
$feature_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
?>
<?php if( $feature_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php while ( $feature_query->have_posts() ) : $feature_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query();?>
```

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to order your posts by a meta value in ascending order? Or do you just want an incrementer each time it loops through a post? Or are you trying to get 4 posts each of each meta_value, assuming you have a meta_value of 2, 3, 4, etc.

Comment: I want it to increment in ascending order starting from 2 and ending at 5. so it would return the post with meta-select=2 then meta-select=3 then meta-select=4 then meta-select=5 and then end. Does that make sense? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, do you want 1 post from each I'm assuming, so if there's 10 posts under `meta-select-2` you want the first post out of the 10 correct?

Comment: yeah. just the first. I also have the meta set to not allow for 2 posts to have the same value so It shouldn't matter I think. But otherwise the first.

Comment: Sorry, just edits to 'posts_per_page'   => 4, I think that is right.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but you can try this:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 4,
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'meta_key'         => 'meta-select',    
    'order'            => 'ASC',
    'orderby'          => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key'     => 'meta-select',
          'value'   => array( 2, 3, 4, 5 ),
          'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
      ),
);
```

Ordering is done by value of meta field `meta-select` in ascending order. Also in `meta_query`, meta value is checked in the array of possible values